# Fixing "read-itunes-as-list: expects a file with XML document as first argument, given "itunes.xml"" for HTDP exercise 200

Tags: racket, itunes, htdp

I'm doing the [HtDP Exercises](https://htdp.org), and I'm having trouble on [Exercise 200](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_two.html#%28counter._itunes-data._%28exercise._ex~3aitunes2%29%29). I did what the book told me, but I kept on getting the same error. No matter what I tried, I always got this:

```
read-itunes-as-list: expects a file with XML document as first argument, given "itunes.xml"
```

I've tried changing the name of `itunes.xml`, and some other things, but they all seemed to fail. Does someone know how to solve this?
Here's my code (so far):

```
; An LTracks is one of:
; – '()
; – (cons Track LTracks)
; Example:
;   (cons (make-track "Wild Child" "Enya" "A Day Without" 227996 2 (make-date 2002 7 17 3 55 14) 20 (make-date 2011 5 17 17 35 13))
;         '())

;(define-struct track
;  [name artist album time track# added play# played])
; A Track is a structure:
;   (make-track String String String N N Date N Date)
; interpretation An instance records in order: the track's 
; title, its producing artist, to which album it belongs, 
; its playing time in milliseconds, its position within the 
; album, the date it was added, how often it has been 
; played, and the date when it was last played
; Example:
;   (make-track "Wild Child" "Enya" "A Day Without" 227996 2 (make-date 2002 7 17 3 55 14) 20 (make-date 2011 5 17 17 35 13))

;(define-struct date [year month day hour minute second])
; A Date is a structure:
;   (make-date N N N N N N)
; interpretation An instance records six pieces of information:
; the date's year, month (between 1 and 12 inclusive), 
; day (between 1 and 31), hour (between 0 
; and 23), minute (between 0 and 59), and 
; second (also between 0 and 59).
; Example:
;   (make-date 2019 7 9 20 35 54)

; modify the following to use your chosen name
(define ITUNES-LOCATION "itunes.xml")

; LTracks
(define itunes-tracks
  (read-itunes-as-tracks ITUNES-LOCATION))
```

And `itunes.xml`:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>Track ID</key><integer>442</integer>
    <key>Name</key><string>Wild Child</string>
    <key>Artist</key><string>Enya</string>
    <key>Album</key><string>A Day Without</string>
    <key>Genre</key><string>New Age</string>
    <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
    <key>Size</key><integer>4562044</integer>
    <key>Total Time</key><integer>227996</integer>
    <key>Track Number</key><integer>2</integer>
    <key>Track Count</key><integer>11</integer>
    <key>Year</key><integer>2000</integer>
    <key>Date Added</key><date>2002-7-17T3:55:14</date>
    <key>Play Count</key><integer>20</integer>
    <key>Play Date</key><integer>3388484113</integer>
    <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2011-5-17T17:35:13
</dict>
```

Comment: What's the content of your `itunes.xml`? If you use this `itunes.xml`, does it work? https://gist.github.com/sorawee/e92eada7d3081b308c5e9fefbcb3def3

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @ghosh I just did.

Comment: @iDoProgramming how did you obtain your `itunes.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, your `itunes.xml` is malformed. For example,

- On the line before the last line, you have `<date>` but there's no corresponding ending tag `</date>`.
- Date format is wrong. E.g., `2002-7-17T3:55:14` should be changed to `2002-07-17T03:55:14`.

If you download `itunes.xml` from https://gist.github.com/sorawee/e92eada7d3081b308c5e9fefbcb3def3 and use it instead, it should work fine.

Where and how did you obtain your original `itunes.xml`?